# dockerhub automated builds - broad github permissions required?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm looking to test automated container builds on Dockerhub, and I see that I need to link my github account to my hub.docker.account.
However, when I click on the 'connect' button, I'm taken to a github authorization page that says:

```
Docker Hub Builder by docker wants to access your larryms account

Repositories
Public and private
This application will be able to read and write all public and private repository data. 
This includes the following:

- Code
- Issues
- Pull requests
- Wikis
- Settings
- Webhooks and services
- Deploy keys
- Collaboration invites
```

This seems far too permissive and overly broad; if I'm understanding it correctly, I need to grant Docker Hub Builder read & **write** access to **all** my github repositories, both public and **private**.

Is there any way to do this using the principle of least privilege, eg only granting Docker Hub Builder necessary rights (hopefully read only) only to ***specific*** github repos?

Comment: AFAIK this is due to how GitHub manage OAuth permissions, and the granularity they allow. See https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes for more details. It is impossible to grant read permissions to private repos without granting write permissions as well.

Comment: Slightly convoluted, but a way to overcome this is to add a specific user to your GitHub org, granting them READ access only to relevant repos. Then, when connecting your dockerhub account to GitHub, sign in with this user, and approve the required scopes. Even though the scopes are very wide, access will still be bound to the actual permissions your user would have in your org.

Comment: @AntonDrukh, thanks for the service account idea.  Agree that it's a bit convoluted, but it does seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post this as an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth scopes on GitHub are indeed wide (see https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes, where you cannot grant read access without granting write access as well). However, the scopes are applied together with the actual permissions the user has on the repo in question. That is, if the user has only read access to repo X, and the user granted an oauth token with read & write scope to dockerhub, dockerhub would only be able to read from repo X on behalf of this user. If the user gets admin access to repo X later on, the already granted access token will not allow admin access, as the scope of the token allows read & write access only.

With this in mind, you can create a dedicated user for dockerhub in your github org, and grant this user read access to relevant repos. Then connect dockerhub to your github account with this user, granting just read access to the selected repos.